# Text Column Problem while union all in MYSQL with SELECT by PHP

Tags: mysql, sql

While I am using `union all` command in PHP, the `haraket` column type is `text` and it takes a very long time to process.

But if I change it to be a `varchar` type everything seems fine.

How can I improve performance without changing the column type from `text` column to `varchar` column.

Here is my code:

```sql
SELECT id,haraket,sevk_tarihi 
FROM
  (SELECT id,haraket,sevk_tarihi 
   FROM depo_fish 
   WHERE depo_onay = 0 
     AND gircik='iade' 
   
   union all 

   SELECT id,haraket,sevk_tarihi 
   FROM planlama  
   WHERE depo_cikis_aparat = 0)t 
ORDER BY sevk_tarihi ASC;"
```

Comment: This is a SQL question,  the php is irrelevant to the issue you're describing.  Please re-tag and restructure it

Comment: ok thanks I did it.

Comment: You need to tag the specific database type you're using as well (e.g. mysql, sql server, oracle etc). Not all SQL is created equal...and remove the php code entirely, leave just the sql, and format it properly so it's not halfway across the page! A definition of your tables and some sample data would help a lot as well. Make it as simple as possible for people to help you. Thanks.

Comment: You've updated the tags but you still need to make the other changes